# How to change the width of a field of an existing OpenERP7 form view (using percentage, no pixels)?

Tags: css, xml, view, odoo, openerp-7

I am modifying a form view in OpenERP7 through inheritance, and I am trying to change the width of some field, and set it to 50% (now is 40%). I had no problems changing the style of this field, even the own width. But it only works if I type pixels. If I type a percentage, the symbol `%` provokes an error. This is my code:

```
<xpath expr="/form//field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
   <attribute name="style">width: 50%;</attribute>
</xpath>
```

It gives an error. But if I turn `%` to `px`, no problems, and changes are made.

However, when I see the code of the original form, there are percentages in the styles and they work without any problems.

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using the width attribute, you need to use % % instead of a single %. The following example illustrates this:

```
style="width: 46%%"
```

I hope this helps you.

Thanks And Regards

Comment: Great! I would not have guessed it ever. Thank you so much!